# Error while querying Data in Spark 2.2 dataframe

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark

i have able to query Restapi data and convert to RDD and Dataframe.
but when i tried to query the column, instead of columnar result, i am getting comma separated value.

Am i missing something?

Code:

```
package Stream
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.fs._
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SaveMode, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel

object SparkRestApi {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val logger = Logger.getLogger("blah")
    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.WARN)
    Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.WARN)

    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .appName("blah")
      .config("spark.driver.memory", "2g")
      .master("local[*]")
      //.enableHiveSupport()
      .getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._

    val url = "https://platform-api.opentargets.io/v3/platform/public/association/filter"
    val result2 = List(scala.io.Source.fromURL(url).mkString)
    val githubRdd2=spark.sparkContext.makeRDD(result2)
    val gitHubDF2=spark.read.json(githubRdd2)
    gitHubDF2.show()
    val mediandf= gitHubDF2.select(col("data.association_score.overall").as("association_score"))
    mediandf.show()

    spark.stop()
  }

}
```

But Result not well formatted. It is comma separated instead of value in well formatted rows.

```
   association_score|
|[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1...|
```

But i am expecting

```
    1.0
    1.0
    1.0
```

Comment: what is your expected output ??

Comment: @Srinivas: i am trying to get value for association_score,disease.id,target.name and target.id from JSON

Comment: @Srinivas: i did test with association_score, but instead of showing value in rows it is shown as comma seperated value.

Comment: I think target.name is not available in your json. check below solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below code.

`Note` You will get duplicates rows if you explode array column values.

```
scala> val url = "https://platform-api.opentargets.io/v3/platform/public/association/filter"
```

```
scala> val df =  spark.read.json(Seq(scala.io.Source.fromURL(url).mkString).toDS)
```

```
scala> df.withColumn("data",explode($"data")).select($"data.association_score.overall",$"data.disease.id".as("disease_id"),$"data.target.id").show(false)
+-------+-------------+---------------+
|overall|disease_id   |id             |
+-------+-------------+---------------+
|1.0    |MONDO_0045024|ENSG00000121879|
|1.0    |MONDO_0023370|ENSG00000121879|
|1.0    |EFO_0000616  |ENSG00000121879|
|1.0    |EFO_0010285  |ENSG00000121879|
|1.0    |MONDO_0045024|ENSG00000133703|
|1.0    |MONDO_0023370|ENSG00000133703|
|1.0    |MONDO_0045024|ENSG00000157764|
|1.0    |MONDO_0023370|ENSG00000157764|
|1.0    |EFO_0000616  |ENSG00000157764|
|1.0    |OTAR_0000018 |ENSG00000157764|
+-------+-------------+---------------+
```